# In Python how would I compare 2 values in one dictionary that have the same values in another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
adict = {"a":(1,2),"b":(3,4),"c":(5,6),"d":(7,8)}
bdict = {"ax":(1,2),"xb":(3,4),"xc":(5,98),"xd":(7,99)}
```

How would I grab the key in bdict.
I want to be able to check if the values in adict can be found in bdict and if they do exisits I can grab the key. 
So the output would be "ax" and "xb" because in adict the both values of key "a" are in bdict. and same with the b values in adict (3,4)

Comment: can you clarify and print an expected output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Whats with all the hate. I'm learning. It takes you guys like 2 mins to figure out. And it would take me hours. Now I know how to do it and it makes sense. Sorry

Comment: No disrespect - you are inferring something that isn't there. The question just needs more focus.

Comment: @AdamGIS There is no hate, I believe I speak for many of us here. But do note that in the guidelines, SO has it mentioned that you need to have your attempt in the code. Even I would not answer questions without any attempt, but in your case the code was very simple and just a couple of loops. You might want to look at this: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/. If you follow all the guidelines here, then I am sure you won't receive any downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for k, v in bdict.items():
  if v in adict.values():
    print(k)
```

It's as simple as iterating on `bdict` and checking if the value exists in `adict.values()`.

---

Or:

```
res = [k for k, v in bdict.items() if v in adict.values()]
print(res)
```

Prints:

```
['ax', 'xb']
```

Comment: I see nice this worked. What if "b":(4,3). How can that match with "xb":(3,4). Is that possible. You know if the values were flipped.

Comment: In your example, it is b: (3, 4). Are you suggesting a new sample input?

Comment: Yeah if it was adict = {"a":(1,2),"b":(4,3),"c":(5,6),"d":(7,8)}
I still would want xb to print.

Comment: That wasn't mentioned in the question. I suggest you take the code from my answer and create a new post with this new requirement. I am sure someone will help you.

Comment: @AdamGIS, whenever you make a new post, you can put the link to the question here and if I have the time and no one has answered it, I will.

Answer (score 1):

The following code return a list of every key in bdict that its value appear in adict, it does so by using list comprehension to create a list of every key that its value appear in the adict.values() (which are all the adict values):

```
matched_values_keys = [bdict_key for bdict_key, bdict_value in bdict.items() if bdict_value in adict.values()]
```

Hope that helped

Comment: You missed a `]`. Also, please explain what the code does not what the code will return because what if the OP hasn't learned the concept of comprehensions?